# How to get li from a href value containing string

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I've got the following html

```
<ul id="navigationMenuTop" class="nav navbar-nav" data-bind="foreach: getRoutes">
  <li data-bind="css: ..." >
    <a data-bind="attr { href: ...">
```

This generates a nice top bar menu where users get to go to parts of the program where they have the rights for.

Now I need to get the li where the href in a contains 'registration'

I've tried several things, the latest being

```
$('.navigationMenuTop li a[href*="registration"]');
```

but no success yet, any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain why do you need to get this `<li>` element?  You are iterating an observable array named `getRoutes`.  Each element of this array should have a property that is used in the binding `attr: { href: ...}`.  This object is where you can modify your `<li>`.

Comment: The getRoutes gets the topside menu tab routes forwarding to different parts of the program. This gets run once at startup.

I am now adding a check to see if there's notifications in a certain part of the program to light up the tab for that part of the program. This check runs every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parent function to get the parent of the matched anchor

```
$('#navigationMenuTop a[href*="registration"]').parent();
```

you can check this out [here](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing few things here.

This is not a knockout question, more of a jQuery + CSS questions.

`navigationMenuTop` is ID - so you shouldn't access it with a `dot` which means class.

Try # instead:

```
$('#navigationMenuTop li a[href*="registration"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#navigationMenuTop").on('click','li',function (){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: this will not suffice as the text displayed will be different depending on the language selected by the user.